# Create dynamic list of tables based on list with wildcards

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql, sql-server-2019

So I have a list of  tables that I want (with wildcards)

```
CREATE TABLE [config].[datalist](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [order] [int] NULL,
    [dbname] sysname NULL,
    [schemaname] sysname NULL,
    [tablename] sysname NULL
) 
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [config].[datalist] ON 
GO
INSERT [config].[datalist] ([id], [order], [dbname], [schemaname], [tablename]) VALUES (1, 1, N'TEST', N'audit*', N'*')
GO
INSERT [config].[datalist] ([id], [order], [dbname], [schemaname], [tablename]) VALUES (7, 2, N'TEST', N'conversie', N'BR')
GO
INSERT [config].[datalist] ([id], [order], [dbname], [schemaname], [tablename]) VALUES (8, 3, N'TEST', N'datalibrary', N'T*')
GO
INSERT [config].[datalist] ([id], [order], [dbname], [schemaname], [tablename]) VALUES (9, 3, N'BIML', N'*', N'*')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [config].[datalist] OFF
GO

SELECT  [id]
      ,[order]
      ,[dbname]
      ,[schemaname]
      ,[tablename]
  FROM [UITWISSEL].[config].[datalist]
```

That gives me

```
id  order   dbname  schemaname  tablename
1   1   TEST    audit*  *
7   2   TEST    conversie   BR
8   3   TEST    datalibrary T*
9   3   BIML    *   *
```

Now what I need is a list of all tables mentioned in the table `config.datalist`

So I want a list of:

id 1) all tables in database `TEST` of which the schemaname starts with `audit`

id 7) all tables in database `TEST` in the schema `conversie` with the name `BR`

id 8) all tables in database `TEST` in schema 'datalibrary' of which the name starts with a `T`

id 9) all tables in database `BIML` in all schema's

I have the following code but I this works only for the database `BIML`.
How to get  this code to work for all databases mentioned in config.datalist.dbname?

```
select distinct  t.name as TableName
, 'SELECT  * FROM ' + quotename(replace(replace(ds.[dbname] ,'[',''),']',''))+'.'+
quotename(s.name)+'.'+
quotename(t.name) AS selectquery 
,s.name as schemaname
,ds.[order]
from BIML.sys.schemas s
left join BIML.sys.tables t on s.schema_id = t.schema_id  
inner join [UITWISSEL].[config].[datalist] ds on s.name like  replace(ds.schemaname,'*','%') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
inner join [UITWISSEL].[config].[datalist] dt on t.name like  replace(ds.tablename,'*','%') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
order by ds.[order] , s.name, t.name
```

That gives me

```
TableName   selectquery schemaname  order
connections SELECT  * FROM [BIML].[config].[connections]    config  3
FilesToImport   SELECT  * FROM [BIML].[config].[FilesToImport]  config  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @i as int = 1
declare @db_list table (id int identity(1,1), dbname sysname, [order] int)
declare @resultlist table ([order] int,dbname sysname, schemaname sysname, tablename sysname, selectquery  nvarchar(4000))
declare @act_dbname sysname
declare @act_order int =1
declare @sql as nvarchar(4000)

insert into @db_list 
select distinct dbname, [order] from UITWISSEL.[config].[datalist] order by [order]

while @i <= (select max(id) from @db_list)
BEGIN

set @act_dbname = (select dbname from @db_list where id = @i)
set @act_order = (select [order] from @db_list where id = @i)
set @sql = '

select distinct  
'+ cast(@act_order as varchar(4)) + ' as [order]
,'''+ @act_dbname +''' as dbname
,s.name as schemaname
,t.name as tablename
, ''SELECT  * FROM '' + quotename('''+ @act_dbname + ''')+''.''+
    quotename(s.name)+''.''+
    quotename(t.name) 
AS selectquery 

from  '+ @act_dbname + '.sys.schemas s  
left join '+ @act_dbname + '.sys.tables t on s.schema_id = t.schema_id  
inner join [UITWISSEL].[config].[datalist] ds on s.name like  replace(ds.schemaname,''*'',''%'') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
inner join [UITWISSEL].[config].[datalist] dt on t.name like  replace(ds.tablename,''*'',''%'') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
order by [order] , s.name, t.name
'
print  @sql 
insert into @resultlist exec sp_executesql @sql
set @i = @i+1
END

select * from @resultlist order by [order], schemaname, tablename
```

Comment: Careful, this attempt introduces injection issues.  The OP properly used `QUOTENAME` when they injected the values, and so too should you.

Comment: I will add that, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* you are parametrising the statement to get the list of tables, then you could do this:

```sql
DECLARE @ListID int = 8; --Your parameter

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @DatabaseName sysname,
        @SchemaName sysname,
        @TableName sysname;

SELECT @DatabaseName = REPLACE(dbname,'*','%'),
       @SchemaName = REPLACE(schemaname,'*','%'),
       @TableName = REPLACE(tablename,'*','%')
FROM config.datalist
WHERE id = @ListID;

SET @SQL = N'SELECT s.[name] AS SchemaName,' + @CRLF +
           N'       t.[name] AS TableName' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + N'sys.schemas s' + @CRLF + 
           N'     JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + N'sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE s.[name] LIKE @SchemaName' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND t.[name] LIKE @TableName;';

PRINT @SQL;
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@SchemaName sysname, @TableName sysname', @SchemaName, @TableName; --Uncomment to run
```